# ngIf inside a ng-repeat gives error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is a simplified idea of my code. `$scope.events` is an multi-dimentional array and my HTML is:

```
<div ng-repeat="event in events" >
   {{event.owner_id.$oid}} //renders the $oid
   <div ng-if="event.owner_id.$oid == 20">
      Code to be rendered if true
   </div>
</div>
```

However I get the following error from angular:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$parse/syntax?p0=a02c36b440519dc1aa6&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=30&p3=event.owner_id."<!-- ngIf: event.owner_id.$oid ==  52408a02c36b440519dc1aa6 -->"id%20%3D%3D%20%2052408a02c36b440519dc1aa6&p4=a02c36b440519dc1aa6
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The logic here looks correct. Did you close your div tags in your code?

Comment: @NicolasMoise yes. it was a typo. The code that exactly gives that error is: `ng-if="event.owner_id.$oid == 52408a02c36b440519dc1aa6 "`

Comment: Well then you need an extra set of quotes because that's a string not a number

Comment: @NicolasMoise Aw, lovely... Thanks, didn't know angular handles these objects as js does.

Comment: @Diolor if you find the solution, you can post it and accept your own answer!

Comment: @GonzaloNaveira I added an answer how I solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since @gonzalo asked it on the comments, I write it:

```
<div ng-if="event.owner_id.$oid == {{user_id}} ">
```

is fine if user_id is 20.

But use:

```
<div ng-if="event.owner_id.$oid == '{{user_id}}' ">
```

if the user_id is not a integer.

Angularjs tries to parse a string without quotes.

Comment: This is not working for me :P, js is just processing the {{}} as a string, not as a the actual value

Comment: @GabrielMatusevich No clue why. Stupid question: Have you loaded the library?